Should we have separate tasks for n number of tasks?
Suppose there are three tasks, A, B, and C, each requiring 10 days to complete.

I started task A but had to stop it after 5 days.
Then I started task B but stopped it after 3 days to resume and
complete task A.
After finishing task A, I completed tasks B and C sequentially.

How can I represent this timeline without splitting task A, or do I need to show task A split into two parts?

You add lead or lag time to the activity. You can also create a roll-up activity that covers the whole work package, with each work item added to the timeline as well.

I do it manually.
Go to the TASK (menu), then to the SCHEDULE GROUP and find the SPLIT TASK icon. On the Gantt Chart, click the bar you want to split on a date where you want to split and drag the second part to correct date. I would love to see if there is any other way - especially by using Predecessors settings.
In this case it is easy as there are only two tasks to manage.
Cheers.

